# A library uses the same package as this project error in android?

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPoyj.png)Error:Execution failed for task ':example:processDebugResources'.

> Error: A library uses the same package as this project: com.ford.openxc.webcam

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried changing/removing duplicated applicationId from the defaultConfig in library's build.gradle? That should resolve your issue.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24767805/1370087)

Comment: Yeah I am also try to change the Application Id or deleting it but still getting the same error.